# Android ADK bluetooth device compatibility

Tags: android, arduino

I am trying to get started with Android ADK.

My goal is to connect Arduino UNO + blue-tooth and Android devices via blue-tooth.

I discovered that ADK needs Linux kernel 2.6.35+ which is used for Android 2.3.4 to allow communication via USB.

So it's clear that all devices should support this requirement for USB communication.

But what about blue-tooth? Does it mean that the same rules applies to blue-tooth interaction?
Is it possible to establish connection and data exchange with device for instance with Android 2.1 (API level 7).

So, any explanations are warmly appreciated

**UPDATE#1**
My primary goal is to connect Android 2.1 device with Arduino via blue-tooth.
My first thoughts were that I should use ADK but I discovered that at least for USB it depends on linux kernel version.
But I think it still may be possible to use blue-tooth instead of USB and possibly I may still use ADK, if not how can I connect Arduino with android via blue-tooth without ADK.

Comment: Hi Can you elaborate your question a bit? As an example explain what you are going to do? I think I can help on this matter.

Comment: I updated my question, please take a look if it make sense for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well.. Not sure I understand your problem exactly but I try to give you the best possible answer I can.

There is no relationship between ADK and Bluetooth. You need ADK if you use a USB cable to connect your ADK compatible development board with your Android mobile. The USB compatible board or the ADK shield contains a USB peripheral controller so it can control the USB devices through cable.

In your case you don't need any physical connection between your Arduino and the android device so it is a matter of Bluetooth connectivity. You just have to use [a cheap Bluetooth Module](http://dx.com/p/jy-mcu-arduino-bluetooth-wireless-serial-port-module-104299?item=11) with your mobile (Not needs to be an Android anyway).

Now you have to connect the Bluetooth module with your Arduino. Now you have two Bluetooth enabled equipment so you are ready to communicate. I found some good tutorials on web that you can use as a starting point.

[How to control Arduino over bluetooth](http://www.instructables.com/id/how-to-Control-arduino-by-bluetooth-from-PC-pock/)

[Arduino Android Bluetooth Communication](http://bellcode.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/android-and-arduino-bluetooth-communication/)

Let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth functionality seems to have been a part of the [Android APIs since level 5](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html). Thus Android 2.1 should work just fine!

Comment: yes, bluetooth functionality is here for a long time, but from this url http://goo.gl/2xMe6 you can see that both, ADK device and Android has special API for blue-tooth interaction, so I wonder is there some other restrictions